# Way to Add newSideBar for blogger (html) im having a sidebar on right side but i need to add one more on leftside

Tags: java, blogger, new-operator, sidebar

[image]

can someone please share the code here pls i appreciate the work i need a new sidebar for my lefthand side  Way to Add newSideBar for blogger (html) im having a sidebar on right side but i need to add one more on leftside  , i just want to insert some information to it and add some display adds around the corner on the left side